# Google Cloud Builder - how to trigger build configuration in a subdirectory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to establish a Google Cloud Builder Build Trigger to autobuild and deploy my [ASP .NET Core application](https://github.com/ismangil/clearbooks-rest/tree/appengine/clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore) to Google AppEngine.

Using the current [cloudbuild.yaml](https://github.com/ismangil/clearbooks-rest/blob/889ffc123c3d48123a472e80f88cf7078f5cb274/clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore/cloudbuild.yaml):

```
   steps:
   - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet'
     args: [ 'publish', '-c', 'Release' ]

   - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
     args: ['app','deploy','./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/app.yaml']
```

I have tested local build working using `cloud-build-local` tool.

These two approach worked locally:

1. From the **application subdirectory**: `cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false .`
2. From the **repository root**: `cloud-build-local --config=clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore/cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore`

The Build Trigger definition seems to partially support config files from a subdirectory of the repository root (approach no 2) however it seems to assume that code always lives in repository root.

How do I configure Cloud Builder to start a build in a subdirectory of the repository?

Comment: guess you need to pass an absolute path for the `--config`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I did that for on the Buid Trigger section and it still doesn't work because it seems to need the source  parameter to match yet the Build Trigger definition screen doesn't expose that.

Comment: What error message or misbehavior do you see?

Comment: @JeffreyRennie I've now solved this by adding `dir:` parameter and testing locally with the correct parameter to reflect how Cloud Build works. Posted as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to update `cloudbuild.yaml`:

1. Add the `dir:` option on the build step
2. Provide the correct `app.yaml` location for deploy step

Here is the working cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet'
  args: [ 'publish', '-c', 'Release' ]
  dir: 'clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app','deploy','clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/app.yaml']
```

When testing locally, run `cloud-build-local` on repository root, never on the app subdirectory:

`cloud-build-local --config=clearbooks-rest-aspnetcore/cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false .`

This reflects the way Cloud Build works:

1. Path to correct cloudbuild.yaml
2. Current directory for source

Comment: This works great Perry thanks! But now the next step is having trouble locating my `app.yaml` in the same subdirectory. There's a configuration option in the trigger to specify where your `cloudbuild.yaml` is but not one for app engine's `app.yaml` unfortunately.

Comment: Just to answer my own question for others coming here: The `app.yaml` file path can be specified as the last value in the `args` section of the `cloudbuild.yaml` under `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud`.

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a sample project with Spring Boot with App Engine and directory structure is like.

```
google-cloud
      - appengine-spring-boot
      - appflexengine-spring-boot
```

below are the **cloudbuild.yaml** file that is working for me.

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    dir: "appengine-spring-boot"
    #args: [ 'package','-f','pom.xml','-Dmaven.test.skip=true' ]
    args: [ 'clean', 'package']
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    dir: "appengine-spring-boot"
    args: [ "app", "deploy" ]
    timeout: "1600s"
```